# How to Edit data from the listbox which is bind to an observablecollection as well as from the isolated storage database

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, listbox

I am working on how to edit data when the user first insert his Name ,age and address and the data is shown on the another page of  windows phone now the user want to edit the item of the listbox which is binded to the observablecollection  .I want to edit AND UPDATE the data in the database as well the List get refreshed.Please help me out

this is my code for the database where i am adding ,deleting and editing

```
 public class SampleData
{
    //Define Method for add a baby detail
    public bool AddSample(Sample sample)
    {
        try
        {
            using (SqliteSampleDataContext sampleDataContext = new SqliteSampleDataContext(SqliteSampleDataContext.DBConnectionString))
            {

                SqliteSampleTable sampleDetail = new SqliteSampleTable();
                sampleDetail.Name = sample.Name;                    
                sampleDataContext.Sample.InsertOnSubmit(sampleDetail);
                sampleDataContext.SubmitChanges();
                return true;
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    //Define Method for delete a baby detail
    public bool DeleteSample(int id)
    {
        try
        {

            using (SqliteSampleDataContext sampleDataContext = new SqliteSampleDataContext(SqliteSampleDataContext.DBConnectionString))
            {
                //Delete Baby object
                var sampleObj = (from item in sampleDataContext.Sample where item.Id == id select item).FirstOrDefault();
                sampleDataContext.Sample.DeleteOnSubmit(sampleObj);
                //babyCareDataContext.SubmitChanges();

                sampleDataContext.SubmitChanges();

                return true;
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

and this is my view model

```
public  class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string property)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
        }

    }

    private ObservableCollection<Sample> _itemsList;
    public ObservableCollection<Sample> ItemsList
    {
        get
        {
            return _itemsList;
        }
        set
        {
            _itemsList = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("ItemsList");
        }
    }  

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        ItemsList = new ObservableCollection<Sample>();

        GetSampleList();
    }

    //Define Method for get baby list
    public void GetSampleList()
    {
        try
        {
            SqliteSampleDataContext sampleDataContext = new SqliteSampleDataContext(SqliteSampleDataContext.DBConnectionString);
            if (sampleDataContext.Sample.Count() > 0)
            {
                this.ItemsList.Clear();
                SampleData objSampleData = new SampleData();
                List<SqliteSampleTable> samples = objSampleData.GetSamples();
                foreach (var item in samples)
                {

                    this.ItemsList.Add(new Sample
                    {
                        Name = item.Name,
                        Id = item.Id
                    });
                }
            }
            else
                this.ItemsList.Clear();
        }
        catch
        {
        }
    }

    public void SaveSampleDetail(Sample sample)
    {
        SampleData objBabyData = new SampleData();
        objBabyData.AddSample(sample);
        App.ViewModel.GetSampleList();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

This is quite a UI centric question, and it just depends on how you want to approach it. To provide the best user experience for your users, in my opinion, it is better to redirect the user to a details view page.

If you have to edit the user details in a list, you could possibly take this approach.

1. Ensure that your model properties implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface
2. Create two converters which can set visibility on a UI control to visible or collapsed state
3. Plumb in your Business logic and your UI code.

For this example, I’m using the mmvmlight framework, you can adapt it to whatever framework you use fairly easily.

**Your converters, Note that you can roll this up into one converter if you prefer, just pass in a command parameter of true or false and then implement the correct logic. I've decided to keep things simple**

```
 public class VisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        bool visible;

        bool.TryParse(value.ToString(), out visible);

        return visible ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class VisibilityInvertedConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        bool visible;

        bool.TryParse(value.ToString(), out visible);

        return visible ? Visibility.Collapsed : Visibility.Visible;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

**User entity**

```
 public class UserInfomation : ObservableObject
{
    #region Properties and Fields

    private string firstName;
    private string lastName;
    private string addressLineOne;

    private bool editMode;

    #endregion

    #region Public Properties

    public string FirstName
    {
        get { return this.firstName; }
        set
        {
            if (this.firstName != value)
            {
                this.firstName = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    public string LastName
    {
        get { return this.lastName; }
        set
        {
            if (this.lastName != value)
            {
                this.lastName = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    public string AddressLineOne
    {
        get { return this.addressLineOne; }
        set
        {
            if (this.addressLineOne != value)
            {
                this.addressLineOne = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    public bool EditMode
    {
        get { return this.editMode; }
        set
        {
            if (this.editMode != value)
            {
                this.editMode = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

**Your viewModel should look similar to:**

```
 public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    #region Properties and Fields

    /// <summary>
    /// A collection of user records.
    /// </summary>
    private ObservableCollection<UserInfomation> users;

    /// <summary>
    /// Command to execute when a record is to be edited.
    /// </summary>
    public RelayCommand<UserInfomation> EditUserDetail { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Command to execute when a record is to be saved.
    /// </summary>
    public RelayCommand<UserInfomation> SaveUserDetail { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Holds the current data that is being edited, if any.
    /// </summary>
    private UserInfomation userDataInEditMode;

    #endregion

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the MainViewModel class.
    /// </summary>
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        this.EditUserDetail = new RelayCommand<UserInfomation>(EditUserDetailAction);
        this.SaveUserDetail = new RelayCommand<UserInfomation>(SaveUserDetailAction);
        this.GenerateData();
    }

    #region Public Properties

    public ObservableCollection<UserInfomation> Users
    {
        get { return this.users; }
        set
        {
            if (this.users != value)
            {
                this.users = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Methods

    private void GenerateData()
    {
        this.Users = new ObservableCollection<UserInfomation>
        {
            new UserInfomation { FirstName = "John", LastName = "Smith", AddressLineOne = "1 John Avenue, Florida" },
            new UserInfomation { FirstName = "Peter", LastName = "Wandsworth", AddressLineOne = "34 Peter Avenue, Denver" },
            new UserInfomation { FirstName = "Emily", LastName = "Stone", AddressLineOne = "1 Emily Avenue, London" }
        };
    }

    private void EditUserDetailAction(UserInfomation userDataToEdit)
    {
        if (userDataInEditMode != null)
        {
            this.userDataInEditMode.EditMode = false;
        }

        this.userDataInEditMode = userDataToEdit;
        this.userDataInEditMode.EditMode = true;
    }

    private void SaveUserDetailAction(UserInfomation userDataToSave)
    {
        //Save your data here:
        if (userDataInEditMode != null)
        {
            userDataInEditMode.EditMode = false;

            MessageBox.Show("first name changed to " + userDataToSave.FirstName);
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

**Finally your UI code**

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage
x:Class="TestApp.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:TestApp.ViewModel"
mc:Ignorable="d"
FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
x:Name="ApplicationPage"
DataContext="{Binding Main, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">

<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <viewModel:VisibilityConverter x:Key="RowVisibilityConverter" />
    <viewModel:VisibilityInvertedConverter x:Key="RowVisibilityInvertedConverter" />
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <StackPanel x:Name="TitlePanel" Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28">
        <TextBlock Text="MY APPLICATION" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}" Margin="12,0"/>
        <TextBlock Text="page name" Margin="9,-7,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
    </StackPanel>

    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Users}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <Border Visibility="{Binding EditMode, Converter={StaticResource RowVisibilityInvertedConverter}}" Width="450" Margin="0 0 0 20" Padding="15" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}">
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition />
                                    <RowDefinition />
                                    <RowDefinition />
                                    <RowDefinition />
                                    <RowDefinition />
                                    <RowDefinition />
                                    <RowDefinition />
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <TextBlock Text="First name" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeMediumLarge}" />
                                <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding FirstName}" Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}" />

                                <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Text="Last name" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeMediumLarge}" />
                                <TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Text="{Binding LastName}" Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}" />

                                <TextBlock Grid.Row="4" Text="Address" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeMediumLarge}" />
                                <TextBlock Grid.Row="5" Text="{Binding AddressLineOne}" Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}" />
                                <Button Grid.Row="6" Content="Edit" CommandParameter="{Binding}" Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.EditUserDetail, ElementName=ApplicationPage}" />
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                        <Border Visibility="{Binding EditMode, Converter={StaticResource RowVisibilityConverter}}" Width="450" Margin="0 0 0 20" Padding="15" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}">
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition />
                                    <RowDefinition />
                                    <RowDefinition />
                                    <RowDefinition />
                                    <RowDefinition />
                                    <RowDefinition />
                                    <RowDefinition />
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <TextBlock Text="First name"></TextBlock>
                                <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding FirstName, Mode=TwoWay}" />

                                <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Text="Last name"></TextBlock>
                                <TextBox Grid.Row="3" Text="{Binding LastName, Mode=TwoWay}" />

                                <TextBlock Grid.Row="4" Text="Address"></TextBlock>
                                <TextBox Grid.Row="5" Text="{Binding AddressLineOne, Mode=TwoWay}" />

                                <Button Grid.Row="6" Content="Save" CommandParameter="{Binding}" Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.SaveUserDetail, ElementName=ApplicationPage}" />
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```